# Maiden name used in flight booking

Tags: passports, poland, easyjet

I am a French citizen. My sister booked a flight on easyjet to Poland for both of us, and she used my maiden name only as my surname.

However, on my passport, the surname reads like this : `maiden_name ép. marital_name`.

Is it ok or do I have to make the change on my booking ?

Comment: Are you flying from France to Poland? If so, you can use other forms of EU id on domestic flights, e.g., those with your photo, such as an identity card or driving license.  Some airlines make it difficult to change the Passenger Name Record. In your case, with how your name is expressed in your passport, you may be okay.