# Married name on easyjet booking

Tags: bookings, airlines, easyjet

I'd like to ask a question that is related to these two posts: ([post 1 on "maiden name on easyjet booking"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99660/maiden-name-used-in-flight-booking)) and ([post 2 on "two given names and one surname"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67600/i-have-two-given-names-and-one-surname-is-it-a-problem-if-i-omit-the-surname-fr)). I am aware that it is possibly a duplicate of number 2, but is was specific enough (both to the situation, and the airline) that I thought I would ask a separate question.

An easyjet booking was made, similar to the one in post 1, but it's the reverse:

The reservation was made with the name on the booking like this: AAAAA CCCCC. 
(AAAAA is the first name)

On the passport, the surname is written like this: BBBBB ep. CCCCC

(this is the French naming convention on passports of married women who opt to have the martial name on the passport, "ép." stands for "épouse" or spouse).

I wanted to find out if anyone knew if easyjet would accept this as is, or if there is a need to change the name on the booking (which obviously, implies fees).

The flight is from Paris to Marrakesh (CDG-RAK).

Thank you!

Comment: Which airports are you flying from/to? If it's a domestic french flight, I expect Easyjet staff to have no problems with it, for instance.

Comment: Hi @jcaron, thanks for the reply. It's Paris to Marrakesh (CDG-RAK). I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this doesn't really answer my own question, but I managed to get Easyjet to change the last name in the booking free of charge.

My guess is they would've allowed the passenger to board since the other last name (CCCCC in my post) is on the passport.

I'll see if I can get a straight answer from Easyjet and will post back here.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your temporary answer. I look forward to your edited version later if you do get the answer. But feel free to accept this answer as it is.

Comment: Cheers. I will do exactly that and will edit my answer once I hear back from easyjet.

Comment: how did you manage to change it with no fees please? As the same thing happened to me :(

Comment: @Rudy Mészáros: I tweeted them, they responded via DM, and then they changed it. I guess what made it easier was that it was an addition to the name rather than a complete name change.

Answer (score 2):

As OP didn't come back with "a straight answer from easyJet":

The page describing "[Fees and Charges](https://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions/fees)" describes a "Name change" as

> If you would like to transfer your booking to a different passenger, you can do so for a fee, but without paying any fare difference. This is cheaper to do further in advance.

It also separately states:

> If you make a spelling mistake, (e.g. Nick to Nicholas, or Joness to Jones) or need to change a title you can do this for no extra charge.

The scenario you describe seems to fit better under the free change for a "mistake" than a name change to "a different passenger"